# Can't find migrate setting in configuration

Tags: 8, migrations

I have installed Migrate and Migrate Drupal in admin/modules.

But after installing these module, I can't find it in configuration.

Drupal version 8.

[image]

[image: configuration page]

Comment: Did you click on configuration up top? and looked in the config page?

Comment: @NoSssweat I have attached configuration page image. I can't find the migrate configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Using the Migrate Upgrade UI (easier)
>
> Migrate Upgrade is a UI for core upgrades from Drupal 6 and Drupal 7
>   to Drupal 8. It's still under heavy development, so things may break.
>   If something fails for you, check the issue queue first! There may be
>   a patch. If not, check with the developers in #drupal-migrate on IRC.
>
> **After installing Migrate Upgrade, visit your Drupal 8 site's /upgrade page.** When you do you will see this helpful Home screen.
>
> [image]

Source: [Executing a Drupal 6/7 to Drupal 8 upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/node/2257723)

**Step 1)** Install [Upgrade Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) module

**Step 2)** Go to `yourwebsite.com/upgrade`

#### Worth Noting

> If you have a Drupal 6 or 7 site you want to upgrade, install or update the Upgrade Status module to get a customized, up-to-date report on the status of your modules and themes in Drupal 8. Once you are ready, Drupal 8 core also includes the Migrate module to update existing Drupal 7 and 6 sites to Drupal 8 directly. **Migrate is marked "experimental" in Drupal 8.0.0, but will be fully supported in an upcoming release**

Source: [Drupal 8.0.0 released](https://www.drupal.org/news/drupal-8.0.0-released)

Comment: I found documentation on this, updated answer.

Comment: Correct, but you should clarify that this is with the additional Migrate Upgrade UI contrib module that needs to be installed separately.

Comment: @Berdir, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't even realise that. Odd that is not included in core, perhaps, because it's not stable yet.